# Register with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to register a user when I send data from the front end to the back end and I use FOSUserBundle. However, when I persist data in the database I get an empty `salt` value.

### Registration Controller:

```
<?php

namespace MedBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MedBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        $m = " saisie votre donnés";
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $username = $request->request->get('username');
            $email = $request->request->get('email');
            $pass = $request->request->get('pass');
            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $user= new User();
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setPlainPassword($pass);
            $user->setEnabled("1");
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $m= "success";
        }

        return $this->render('default/registere.html.twig',array('m' => $m));
     }
}
```

### User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    protected $id;
    protected $username;
    protected $email;
    protected $plainPassword;
    protected $enabled;
    protected $salt;
    protected $roles;

    // ...
}
```

and when I set

```
$user->setSalt('hello');
```

I have a bug where `salt` is empty.

Comment: why do you use fosuser if you do your own register ?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the `salt` manually either.

Comment: Both comments above are right on. You are using the FOSUserBundle which will handle the registration on its own. You're doing all the work. Why use it at all?

Comment: you getting fos user manager but never using it. you need provide a user with fos user manager ( if you want to use fos user manager )

Comment: Ok I understood what you disez my friends but I burden a search I find that there is a method for used Register of fosuserbundle , in my case I have a devéloppée application by angular and I can make authentication by angular js rated frontend and symfony backend side , there is t he example for me to éxpliquée how Cà and thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bcrypt it uses built in salts, therefore you don't store the salt in your database.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/946